# Magento 2 Inline translate for script strings

Tags: magento2, javascript, script, inline

I had spent more than 3 hours, but did not find solution.
If subscribe field on home page empty we will get JS message 'This is a required field.' How it may be translated by inline translate (using book on FE). When I inserted to the table TRANSLATE (by sql) string manually, it's working. So, how show book for inline translation for js popups errors?
[image]

I try use this in my subscribe.phtml, but this not work correctly (translated data added to DB, but original string "This is a required field." is empty. why?)

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'jquery/ui',
        'mage/translate'
    ], function ($) {
        $(window).load(function () {
            $.mage.__(<?php echo json_encode(__('This is a required field.'))?>);
        });
    });
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found solution for CSV translates, but not for inline.

**1.** Add to CSV:

**"This is a required field.","This is a required field!!!"**

**2.** Add code to phtml:

```
<script>
require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/translate'
], function ($) {
    $(window).load(function () {
        var translates = <?php echo \Zend_Json::encode(
            array(
                'This is a required field.' => __('This is a required field.'),
            )
        )?>;
        $.mage.translate.add(translates);
    });
});
</script>
```